# Laravel - Prevent non admin users from accessing the dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am preventing users who do not have a role of 'admin' from logging in to the dashboard in a Laravel 5.5 app like this in app/http/Controllers/auth/LoginController.php..

```
   protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');

        return array_add($credentials, 'type', 'admin');
    }
```

This works well, but if somebody resets their password using the forgotten password function then it bypasses this function and lets them in to the dashboard.

How can I lock the dashboard down to prevent this happening?

Should I disable auto login after password reset, will this be enough?

Comment: Create a middleware that redirects the user if it's not an admin.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware), you will have full control on all requests in your app.

Also, you might want to have a look at (spatie/laravel-permission) @ github it will make your Role/Permission process really easier.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the `authenticated` method in `LoginController`. Place the code below in the LoginController.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( Use your Logic here ) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.home');
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
```